# How to return an error message with a 401?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

This seems to change every other year.

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Terms not accepted." };

throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

The problem here is that the framework doesn't know what `HttpResponseException` is.

So, what does one do now?

Answer (score 0):

Halleluyah!

```
   return StatusCode(401, "Hello World!");
```